# I am not getting response from REST API using Retrofit Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

Below is the Response which I am getting from REST API

```
{
"statusCode": "200",
"statusData": "Updated Successfully",
"responseData": {
"bookingId": null,
"customerName": null,
"customerMobileNumber": null,
"patientMobileNumber": null,
"driverMobileNumber": "9090909090",
"deviceToken": "f4kc2epndRA:APA91bEXrl4OmlfRUU2M_mfj3khz53_-OgrOk_lpdYWg8hz4hN4yWEogL3eMobH9nPERyO13UN88zQQDUZn262VBv3gICv9BcNECppuJ_G0SlE-1qn57X5w9kMN_q9MXb6ilXQnlIl0A",
"bookedBy": null,
"emergencyType": null,
"emergencyLatitude": 17.443277115352867,
"emergencyLongitude": 78.45206458121537,
"emergencyGeoHashCode": null,
"hospital": null,
"customerId": 0,
"bookingForSelf": 0,
"bookingStatus": "ACCEPTED",
"customerApp": null,
"groupTypeId": 0,
"groupId": 0,
"gcmToken": null,
"hospitalLatitude": 17.8979999,
"hospitalLongitude": 78.7879989,
"hospitalGeoHashCode": null,
"vehicleNumber": null,
"driverName": "santhosh",
"ambulance_start_latitude": 17.786889,
"ambulance_start_longitude": 78.786999,
"vehicle_id": 1,
"booking_id": 201708240006,
"accepted_datetime": 1503556227596,
"vehicleAttributes": null,
"driverImage": "XXXXXX/pic1.png",
"duration": null,
"distance": null
}
}
```

Below is the Code which I have tried, `BookingAcceptedResponseData` is the POJO Class

```
    final Call<BookingAcceptedResponseData> upDBooking = apiService.updateBookingStat(updateBookingMap);

    upDBooking.enqueue(new Callback<BookingAcceptedResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BookingAcceptedResponseData> call, Response<BookingAcceptedResponseData> response) {

            System.out.println("####### Basic updateBookingStat response.body() : "+response.body());
            System.out.println("####### Basic toString updateBookingStat response.body() : "+response.body().toString());

            try {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    System.out.println("####### updateBookingStat response.body() : "+response.body().toString());
                    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
                    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    //it.putExtra("bookingDetails", bookingDetails);

                                        finish();

                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BookingAcceptedResponseData> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting Response as `packageName@XXXX` from REST API Call I am not getting the actual data.Please help me.

Comment: Write your printed output over here...

Comment: @naveen can you post `BookingAcceptedResponseData` class

Answer (score 1):

Your Response JSON Object contains JSON Object name `responseData` to get `responseData` you need to make below change. try this might help you.

Change response BookingAcceptedResponseData to below BookingAcceptedResponse class

```
public class BookingAcceptedResponse{
    private int statusCode;
    private String statusData;
    private BookingAcceptedResponseData responseData; 
    //TODO 
    //generate getter and setter
}
```

Inside retro call response method change

```
response.body().getResponseData();
```

This will return you proper data

Comment: Hi Akhilesh Patil, I will try it. Thanks for the Response.

Comment: @naveen I made change in my answer please have look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153000/discussion-between-akhilesh-patil-and-naveen).

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the response like
`response.body().string()`

Comment: I have tried but it is getting as same response "packageName@XXXX"